# Multiple Clicks on a Button in MS Word - Visual Basic

Tags: vba

I am creating a document in word with buttons that the user clicks to add text into a text box.

For example - clicking button 1 will add "You've clicked button 1" to text box 1.
Clicking button 2 will add "You've clicked button 2" to the same box. (Exciting stuff I know).

I'm using **TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "You've clicked button 1"** within a Click event in Visual Basic.

I'd like the user to be able to click the buttons again to be able to remove (or undo?) the text. Or, indeed, click a third time to add the text back in again.

I guess I want the user to be able to toggle the text in the box or not. Maybe even change the button colour based on whether the text is on/off or in/out of the text box.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "You've clicked button 1"` <- This means, concatenate the content of textbox and "You've clicked button 1" and write it to textbox. You want to overwrite the content on every click. In that case there is no need to use `+`. Write the content directly to the textbox. I wont give you answer, though I can.

Comment: It is kinda messy undo text changes like that. From what I understood, you want the user to click buttons to create a text based on some options. I suggest you use checkboxes instead of buttons, since it is much more easier to do such tasks

Comment: And to concatenate text in VBA use `&` instead of `+`

Comment: Thanks for this - but - I have several buttons. Each button has a statement attached to it that could be entered into one overall text box. Essentially - the statement is on or off. The user is compiling a report made up of the statements attached to the buttons. It's up to them which order they have the sentences. I don't want to empty the entire text box - just the phrase associated with the button.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would probably do this is to have a simple IF statement that first determines the state of the text. If it's empty, then populate it. If it's not empty, then make the value equal to "".

The code would look something like this (but not exactly - this is just theoretical)

```
If textbox1.text = "" Then

textbox1.text = "You've clicked button 1"

Else 

textbox1.text = ""

End If
```

Apologies if I haven't understood the requirement correctly.

Comment: If there are two click texts, perhaps with like and replace.

Comment: Thanks for this - but - I have several buttons. Each button has a statement attached to it that could be entered into one overall text box. Essentially - the statement is on or off. The user is compiling a report made up of the statements attached to the buttons. It's up to them which order they have the sentences. I don't want to empty the entire text box - just the phrase associated with the button.

Comment: Maybe I could have a Double Click action that first searches the textbox for the exact string of the phrase attached and replace it with """" if it's there? How could I do that?

Comment: If you're populating the box with a variety of different strings, and subsequently making the contents of it one large string, you want to take a look at using the InStr method. You can basically locate strings inside other strings using InStr. So yes - you could have a function that takes an argument (the string) from whatever button you have pressed, searches for that string in the box. If found, delete it, if not found, add it. I think I understand what you're trying to do but haven't really tried anything similar myself.

Comment: OK - I've created this...'Private Sub CommandButton1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
TextBox1 = Selection


    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Hi there, VBA master!"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll'
 <br> But it wipes the entire contents of the box (not the string




End Sub